# How to calculate the conditional probability $p([x,y]|x=y)$?

Tags: multivariate-analysis, conditional-probability, constrained-regression

How do you find conditional probability in a Multivariate Normal subject to the conditions of relationships in the individual variables?

To write it mathematically,
Given the fact that,

[image: Multivariate Normal]

How can we calculate:
[image]

Comment: Then try writing out the definition of a conditional probability. That gets you a good deal of the way to an answer.